# Printing pdf using Node js and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, pdf

Tried creating a pdf using chrome-remote-interface Node js module. When I try to pass arguments to printToPDF function, I get the same output as the one with not arguments.

Page Ref: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/

Look into printToPDF function.

My code for printing pdf.

> ```
> const pdf = await Page.printToPDF({landscape: 'true',displayHeaderFooter: 'true',printBackground: 'true',scale: '1.0',paperWidth: '8.5',paperHeight: '11',marginTop: '0.4',marginBottom: '0.4',marginLeft: '0.5',marginRight: '0.5',pageRanges: ""});
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, print to pdf supports parameters only from version 60. That's why it didn't work